# Node Acess User Reference and Organic Groups permissions

Tags: 7, organic-groups, users

I am using Organic Groups to give group-specific content to users.

The groups' permissions do not allow simple group members to edit group content.

By using the Node Acess User Reference module I wanted to grant permission to specific group members to edit specific nodes on an ad-hoc basis.

The devel information that I get is that allthough that rule works, it is being overriden by OG's permissions thus still not allowing the user to edit the node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, http://drupal.org/node/1171834#comment-6019078 answers it.